# Search does not work for dynamically created rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery Datatables and I have a HTML page where I am displaying records from database in a table. Initially the table is loaded with 50 records and then I am appending 50 records each time it scrolls to bottom.

Now, jQuery DataTables search function works fine for first 50 records but it can not recognize the other records which are dynamically created during infinite scroll.

HTML and DataTables initialization:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('body #new_table').dataTable( {
    'scrollX': true,
    'scrollY': 600,
    'paging':   false,
    "ordering": false,
    'info' : false,
    'aaSorting': []

 });
});
```

```html
<table id="new_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ChemicalID</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Manufacturer</th>
      <th>Registered Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="items" class="display table table-bordered">
    @foreach($data as $chemical)
    <tr class="item">
      <td>{{$chemical->ChemicalID}}</td>
      <td>{{$chemical->Product}}</td>
      <td>{{$chemical->Manufacturer}}</td>
      <td>{{$chemical->RegisteredName}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

If you're just appending `tr` nodes to the table, search will not find those rows as jQuery DataTables is not aware of them.

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`row.add()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add%28%29) or [`rows.add()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add%28%29) API methods to add new rows, only then new rows would be visible to jQuery DataTables.

For example, to add a new row to the table and redraw:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.row.add([
    "Tiger Nixon",
    "System Architect",
    "Edinburgh",
    "61",
    "2011/04/25",
    "$320,800"
]).draw(false);
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72pnoxug/1/) for demonstration.

To add a new row to the table using `tr` node and redraw:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.row.add($(
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Tiger Nixon</td>' +
    '<td>System Architect</td>' +
    '<td>Edinburgh</td>' +
    '<td>61</td>' +
    '<td>2011/04/25</td>' +
    '<td>$320,800</td>' +
    '</tr>'
)).draw(false);
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72pnoxug/) for demonstration.

Comment: @user3783146, then please mark the answer as accepted, by that future visitors can see that this was a reliable solution.

Comment: it works but shows duplicate when adding data